# ¿Cómo pasar un JSON desde WebAPI y consumirlo en el controlador con JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tengo el siguiente código en mi API:

```
public string GetMLPublishDefinition()
{
   string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MLPublishDefinition);
   return JSON;
}
```

Y en mi controlador, quiero consumirlo de esta forma:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Buscar(Buscador v)
{   
    List<MyListaObjeto> resultados;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:24842/api/MLPublishDefinitions"); 
    resultados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MLPublishDefinition>>(json); 
    v.Resultados = resultados;
    return View("Index", v);
}
```

Agregué esto en el `webapiconfig`:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new    MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Y me tira el siguiente error:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MLPublishDefinition].

Comment: pero ese error se esta generando cuando pasa por el JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() ? entiendo que el MyListaObjeto el cual serializas no es lo mismo que MLPublishDefinition por eso no puede convertir de uno a otro

Comment: si, ahi agregue esa parte del codigo. uso el mismo modelo tanto en la api como en la pagina que consume el servicio.

Comment: que funcionalid cumple el metodo GetMLPublishDefinition() ? porque no le veo mucho sentido. REcomendaria que teniendo el json como string lo pases en http://json2csharp.com/ para validar que la estructura del codigo que usas para deserializar mapea correctamente

Answer (score 1):

Usando WebAPI de ASP.NET MVC 5, si tienes configurado el `JsonFormatter` (y diría que viene por defecto, no hay que tocar nada) no es necesario que serialices los datos a mano, es decir, en tu controlador puedes poner esto:

```
public MLPublishDefinition GetMLPublishDefinition()
{
    return MLPublishDefinition;
}
```

Y para que `httpClient.GetStringAsync` obtenga el JSON de la API no hay que hacer nada especial tampoco, simplemente llama al método adecuado de la API y te devolverá un JSON.

Por otro lado, no sé si será un error en la pregunta, el método que consultas no es el mismo, este de arriba solamente devuelve un elemento y por lo visto intentas obtener un listado.

Answer (score 1):

Tira ese error debido a que en tu api serializas `MLPublishDefinition` y en tu `Controller` quieres desearializar `List<MLPublishDefinition>`, la solución sería que deserialices el mismo tipo de objeto ajustando esta línea en tu `Controller` cambiando esta línea:

```
resultados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MLPublishDefinition>>(json);
```

Por esta:

```
resultados = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MLPublishDefinition>(json);
```

O en su caso, que en tu api regreses:

```
string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List<MLPublishDefinition>);
```